# Sharepoint 2007 Current User

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to use the object model of Sharepoint 2007 to make some changes over a list and read users and groups web settings...

For that I developed a Web Service (WCF) that is stored in the same web application as the sharepoint site in IIS.

Thats working.

I call inside the Web service

> SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

and thats user is not me, is "Sharepoint\System"

Why?

Other thing is that web I try to get all users using

> SPContext.Current.Web.users

that only contain "Sharepoint\System", not the others.

WHY!!!

I give the full trust in the web.config and use the Ntlm authentication method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like the issue is the account that your web service is running under. I would change the application pool that your web service is using and set the identity to a named account. Then, when you query the current user in Sharepoint, you should see the named account you identified in the application pool.

Answer (score 1):

You did follow this guide?

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-9-Getting_SPContextCurrent_in_a_SharePoint_2007_WCF_Service.aspx